# How to add autoincrement for a non primary key coloumn using trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

How can i implement two auto increment fields in a table. i found this can be done with trigger.

already done trigger autoincrement for varchar field, now need autocrement for another field (int)

```
Trigger
========

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_customer_details_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON customer_details
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO customer_details_seq VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.Customer_id = CONCAT('CUST', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 3, '0'));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

What i need is to set auto increment for fields "**customer_id**" and "**Slno**".

where **Customer_id** (Varchar) is Primary Key and done auto increment using the above trigger.

Now i need to add auto increment for **Slno** (Int) in the same table.

Thanks,
Acube

Comment: How about a composite key on your `varchar` and `int auto ..` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_customer_details_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON customer_details
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    set NEW.IntId = coalesce((select max(IntId) from customer_details), 0) + 1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But why not just use an `auto_increment` column?  That is what it is there for.

Comment: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table

Comment: #1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: @acube . . . If you want to do both actions, but the logic in one trigger.

Comment: but i add it in one trigger and its showing me error

Comment: @acube . . . Please edit your question and show the definition of that trigger.

Comment: after adding this trigger, i am getting error message like **Warning: #1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'Slno' at row 1**  But the values are inserted and the two fields are auto incremented. What about this warning..!!!

Comment: Its working after i change the Slno field to varchar datatype. but is it possible with int datatype.

Comment: Now its working after changing the field **Slno** to int datatype and setting it to null.

Answer (score 0):

The following trigger can do the job you need:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `tg_customer_details_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `customer_details`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `customer_details_seq` (`id`) VALUES (0);
    SET NEW.`customer_id` := CONCAT('CUST', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 3, '0'));
END*/$$

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27ba2/1)</kbd>

The strange thing about the design that need another sequence for the `customer_id` column of the table `customer_details`. Why is that?